# How to interpret the OSGeo4w software version under Advanced Install option?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase

When choosing to install QGIS Desktop using the OSGeo4w advanced install option, I noticed that there are what looks like ambiguous software versions to choose.

For example, currently QGIS Desktop is:
1.8.0-4
or if you click on the version, it changes to
1.8.0-3

and under the libraries to choose:
OGR FileGDB Driver (Is this the ESRI API)
1.9.2-1 
or if you click on the version, it changes to 
1.9.0-1

What does the number after the hyphen refer to?  It seems like it could install any number of versions, but likely it has a specific meaning.  Thanks!

(I'm going to install QGIS Desktop with FGDB support, and I think GDAL 1.9.0 is the one that's been proven to work with QGIS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version number usually has the format x.y.z, while the number after the dash is the package number.

The full package list can always be found here:
http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/versions.html

For stability reasons, you have sometimes the choice between several packages available. You can read more on this here: http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/PackagingInstructions